# Word characteristics

Tags: wordplay, tribond

What is the special characteristic of the following words: coughing, thirsty, defiant

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Try reading the help section to figure out what it expected here. I like the bit about [what is considered on-topic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it also points to some other good pages. The question itself is fine but it's not expected that you would post the answer yourself. Instead, if someone else figures it out, you click the check mark next to the question to mark it as accepted (I.E., the right answer). Only you can do this because you posted the question. Take a look around and welcome to puzzling.

Answer (score 7):

They each have:

> Three consecutive letters from the alphabet.

So:

> Cou**ghi**ng, thi**rst**y, and **def**iant

Answer (score -4):

Each word has

> 3 consecutive letters of the alphabet-
>   couGHIng (GHI)
>   thiRSTy (RST)
>   DEFiant (DEF)

Comment: Why have you answered your own question within 2 minutes of asking it?

Comment: because I'm new to stackexchange..learning as I go..

Comment: @pip, nice to have you here - generally you should allow for approximately 24 hours before revealing the answer to your puzzle; this allows users from all around the world to have a chance to answer your puzzle before seeing the solution. :)